# about series and integral - solve $\int_1^2 (x^2-x)dx$ by limit of definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

So I have to compute $$\int_1^2 (x^2-x)dx$$ by using the Riemann sums.
I got stuck the point where I got to $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{i=0}^n (i^2+in).$$

Can I split the sum? If I can then I know how to continue. so the question is:

- can I split the sum? why can I? because as I know for only finite sums it's ok to split, however about the infinite once I'm not sure.
- if It's not legal to split the sum, I would appreciate some hint to the correct direction of solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Your sum IS finite. You are taking a limit afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each value of $n$, the sum is finite, so it is legal to split it. In other words, you are taking sums before taking limits...

Answer (score 2):

When you see $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{i=0}^n (i^2+in)$$
you should really be thinking
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left[\frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{i=0}^n (i^2+in)\right]\text{.}$$
So you would perform $$\frac{1}{n^3} \sum_{i=0}^n (i^2+in)$$ **before** taking the limit. Since you have a finite sum here, it is legal to split the sum.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{1}^{2}(x^2-x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}(z^2+z)\,dz\tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ I = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2+kn}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left[2\binom{k}{2}+(n+1)\binom{k}{1}\right]\tag{2} $$
and:
$$ I = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\left[2\binom{n+1}{3}+(n+1)\binom{n+1}{2}\right] = \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}=\color{red}{\frac{5}{6}}.\tag{3}$$